# ¿Cómo insertar todos los datos de una tabla en otra, en Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g

**Situación:**

Se tiene la siguiente tabla llamada `P_FAMILIA`:

```
|ID |    NAME    | SOLDADOS   |
|---|------------|------------|
| 1 | Stark      |  30000     |
| 2 | Targaryen  |            |
| 3 | Lannister  |  15000     |
| 4 | Greyjoy    |            |
```

Se requiere construir una consulta sql, para pasar todos los campos de la tabla anterior (los datos suministrados son de ejemplo, puede tener muchos más registros) a otra tabla llamada `P_DIAFAMILIA` agregando el número 1, es decir luego de ejecutar la consulta obtener

```
|ID |IDP_FAMILIA|    NAME    | SOLDADOS   |
|---|-----------|------------|------------|
| 1 |    1      | Stark      |  30000     |
| 1 |    2      | Targaryen  |            |
| 1 |    3      | Lannister  |  15000     |
| 1 |    4      | Greyjoy    |            |
```

**Esquema**

```
CREATE TABLE P_FAMILIA
(
ID INT,
NAME VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
SOLDADOS FLOAT(126)
);

ALTER TABLE P_FAMILIA
ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);

CREATE TABLE P_DIAFAMILIA
(
   ID            INT NOT NULL,
   IDP_FAMILIA   INT NOT NULL,
   NAME          VARCHAR2 (30 BYTE),
   SOLDADOS      FLOAT (126)
);


ALTER TABLE P_DIAFAMILIA
ADD( FOREIGN KEY (ID)
REFERENCES P_FAMILIA (ID));

-- Insert Statements
Insert into P_FAMILIA
   (ID, NAME, SOLDADOS)
 Values
   (1, 'Stark', 30000);
Insert into P_FAMILIA
   (ID, NAME)
 Values
   (2, 'Targaryen');
Insert into P_FAMILIA
   (ID, NAME, SOLDADOS)
 Values
   (3, 'Lannister', 15000);
Insert into P_FAMILIA
   (ID, NAME)
 Values
   (4, 'Greyjoy');
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sintaxis básica, para insertar todos los registros de una tabla en otra es:

```
INSERT INTO TABLA_DESTINO
   SELECT * FROM TABLA_ORIGEN;
```

Para este caso particular, la consulta sería:

```
INSERT INTO P_DIAFAMILIA (ID,
                          IDP_FAMILIA,
                          NAME,
                          SOLDADOS)
   SELECT '1',
          ID,
          NAME,
          SOLDADOS
     FROM P_FAMILIA
```